# Getting Size of a child Widget to a Parent Widget after rendering time in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting the following exception, when I run the attached flutter code:

What amends should I do to the code to correct the exception?

P.S.
The `size` variable should change when I vary the `_maxColumns` and `_maxRows` variables in the `getUnits()` method under the `Grid()` class.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The getter 'width' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: width
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );

GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Size size;
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  _afterLayout(_) {
    _getSizes();
  }

  _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    size = renderBox.size;
    print("SIZE of Box: $size");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Grid Demo'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Container(
                  width: size.width,
                  height: size.height,
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  child: Grid(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 200),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Grid extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Positioned> getUnits() {
    double _unitRadius = 50;
    List<Positioned> _units = [];
    double _leftCoordinate = 0;
    double _bottomCoordinate = 0;
    double _margin = 5;
    double _stepFromLeft = _unitRadius + _margin;
    double _stepFromBottom = _unitRadius + _margin;

    //when number of rows and columns change the size variable should change
    int _maxColumns = 20;
    int _maxRows = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < _maxRows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < _maxColumns; j++) {
        _units.add(Positioned(
            bottom: _bottomCoordinate,
            left: _leftCoordinate,
            child: Container(
              width: _unitRadius,
              height: _unitRadius,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('$i $j')),
            )));
        _leftCoordinate += _stepFromLeft;
      }
      _leftCoordinate = 0;
      _bottomCoordinate += _stepFromBottom;
    }

    return _units;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      key: _key,
      children: getUnits(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your `size` variable in `initState`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  size = Size(0.0, 0.0);
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
}
```

Then, in your `_getSizes` method, change it's content when everything is built

```
_getSizes() {
  final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  setState(() {
    size = renderBox.size;
    print("SIZE of Box: $size");
  });
}
```

**Edit**
If you simply want to use `SingleChildScrollView` inside `Column` widget, wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` in `Flexible` like this

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Grid(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 50,
    ),
    Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 200),
  ],
),
```

Don't forget to remove `width` and `height` properties in the `Container`, and `size` variable is not necessary anymore, so you can remove it

Comment: this solution is not working. The print statement is giving me a value of SIZE of Box: Size(0.0, 0.0)

Comment: Because it does not make any sense to use the GlobalKey in a Widget on which you'll extract size to build it's parent.

Comment: the problem I have is that for the  SingleChildScrollView Widget with horizontal scroll direction to work, the child Container should have the size (i.e. width and height ) of the Grid() widget. How do you suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: I am now getting the following exception: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. and RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#d30b2 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1920 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Oooh, sorry, I didn't notice the `Axis.horizontal` part. Yes, you are right indeed. You must wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` in Widget which height is known in advance.

Comment: for this case the Container which has the Grid() widget should have known width and height. This ideally should be the width and height of the Stack widget under the Grid() widget. Any more suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Replace `Expanded` with `Flexible`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227451/discussion-between-malith-kuruppu-and-dm-tr).